# "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-10, fann

I [install Fast Artificial Neural Network Library](https://pypi.org/project/fann2/) in Python 3.7:

```
pip install fann2
```

Exception:

> Collecting fann2
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/a1/fed455d25c34a62d4625254880f052502a49461a5dd1b80854387ae2b25f/fann2-1.1.2.tar.gz
>
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> Looking for FANN libs...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in
>
> line 92, in 
> build_swig()
>
> line 85, in build_swig
> find_fann()
>
> line 66, in find_fann
> raise Exception("Couldn't find FANN source libs!")
> Exception: Couldn't find FANN source libs!
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\mypath\pip-install-ilv2i8yp\fann2\

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Download [Fast Artificial Neural Network Library](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/2012/01/fann-2-2-0-released/):

   ```
   wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/fann/fann/2.2.0/FANN-2.2.0-Source.zip
   unzip FANN-2.2.0-Source.zip
   cd FANN-2.2.0-Source/
   cmake .
   sudo make install
   sudo aptitude install swig
   ```
2. Install Python bindings:

   ```
   sudo aptitude install pip
   sudo pip install fann2
   ```

Answer (score 1):

[Installation from source on Windows](https://github.com/FutureLinkCorporation/fann2#windows-considerations):

- Install Visual C++ Build Tools;
- Install [FANN source code](https://github.com/libfann/fann), using cmake;
- Copy "fanndouble.lib" from FANN installed files to ${python_libs_directory} as "doublefann.lib";
- Install swig for Windows (you will need to set an Enviroment Variable for "swig.exe");
- Run > python setup.py install from PowerShell/Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows prebuilt package:

```
pip3 install pipwin
pipwin install fann2
```

This is equivalent to downloading and installing the package [from archive](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).